# Link redirects to Play Store when I want it to open in app

Tags: applications, google-play-store, hyperlinks

This happens to me a lot, but let's use today's example. I click a SoundCloud link on Facebook, it redirects me to the Play Store to install the SoundCloud app. Fair enough. I install it and go back to Facebook to click the link again to open in app. Again, I get sent to the SoundCloud app in Play Store. Now, it is obviously installed already so I click open, but when I do it, seems like the link has been forgotten on the way, so I only get to the SoundCloud home page.

This happens to me with many links and many apps, opened from both Chrome and Facebook.

Any tips on how to fix this minor bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Google Hangouts. If you request the Desktop version of the Google Play Store on Chrome, it will load the Hangout appropriately, but not from the mobile version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the default actions for the Google Play store App from Android Application Settings to get an option to choose the app which launches the link from Facebook.

- Go to System Settings > Apps > Google Play Store
- Press the "clear defaults" button to clear all the default actions set for Google Play Store

After you do this, clicking on the link should let you choose the app (e.g., SoundCloud) that you want to launch the link with.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Facebook and its Messenger app are set to open links externally.

Comment: This is a good idea, but to be helpful you need to [edit] your answer and explain further. *How* does one make sure that they are set to open links externally?

Comment: AFAIR, this is a setting inside the Facebook app and the Messenger app, not a general Android settings.