# Links redirecting to Google Play store instead of app

Tags: google-play-store

I have this annoying problem where when i open a link, that should direct me directly to an app, it opens the app in Google Playstore like i haven't downloaded it. When i then press "open" on the app in Google Playstore, because i already have downloaded the app, it seems like it has forgotten the link, and i get sent to the frontpage of the app instead of the specific thing, the link originally linked to.

Can anybody please help me with this problem? It's so annoying thay i can't open links.

Comment: example link please

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts. We have an existing question about the same situation: [Link redirects to Play Store when I want it to open in app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160462/44325). Does any of the answers help?

Comment: This could fx. be a link to a tik tok, where i can't open it in the app and therefore i cant whatch it